# Sending multiple events to GTM - Best practices?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a web page that displays various promotions, and depending on the user's engagement, there could be between 10 to 20 promotions visible at once.

For every promotion a user sees, I want to send an event to Google Tag Manager (GTM) which then forwards it to Google Analytics 4 (GA4).

Here's the challenge: If I push multiple events to GTM almost simultaneously, GTM seems to register the data correctly. However, when it's forwarded to GA4, I'm noticing some duplicate entries.

ex:

```
dataLayer2.push({
        event: 'view_promotion',
        ecommerce: {
          items: [
            {
              item_id: 1
            }
          ]
        }
      });
      dataLayer2.push({
        event: 'view_promotion',
        ecommerce: {
          items: [
            {
              item_id: 2
            }
          ]
        }
      });
```

As a temporary fix,
I've introduced a delay, ensuring events are sent one at a time, every second

But I'm curious:

- Can we send several events in quick succession to GTM (e.g., using dataLayer.push()) and have them integrated flawlessly with GA4?
- Is there a best practice for sending multiple events to GTM, especially with GA4 in the mix?

Comment: Have you instead tried to add the events as an array of events? All .push does is an item *or items* to an array. Add them all as an array in one .push.